# Bulk find and remove parts of HTML files using CMD or JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, xpath, sed, html-parsing

Suppose I have set of text .html files in the folder.

I need to process each file and remove contents of specific HTML tags including tags themselves. Files must be rewritten after processing.

Examples:

1. remove all `<script>` blocks
2. remove all `<div class="test-class">` blocks including inner content

Regex tools like `sed -i -e 's/REGEX//g' *.html` are not good for HTML processing. So I am looking for solution focused on HTML parsing based for example on XPATH like `//script` , `//div[@class="test-class"]`.

What is the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: I suggest to use an XML/HTML parser (xmlstarlet, xmllint ...).

Comment: If you [edit] your question to include an example with concise, testable sample input and expected output then I expect you'll get help.

Answer (score 2):

To edit all .html files in current directory with xmlstarlet:

```
xmlstarlet edit --inplace --omit-decl --delete '//script' --delete '//div[@class="test-class"]' *.html
```

---

See: `xmlstarlet edit --help`

This might help with a broken html file:

```
xmlstarlet format --recover --html file.html |\
  xmlstarlet edit --omit-decl --delete '//script' --delete '//div[@class="test-class"]' > new.html
```

Comment: thanks @Cyrus. But the problem with `xmlstarlet` is that it is very sensitive to html formatting and produces errors like `Opening and ending tag mismatch` , `Couldn't find end of Start Tag html`. It doesn't have any built-in html normalization tools and I don't see simple way how to format html files before passing them to xmlstarlet.

Comment: @AlexDasata you could first run the files through HTML Tidy http://www.html-tidy.org/ https://github.com/htacg/tidy-html5 before passing them to xmlstarlet